# req.cookies not working in express js (cookie-parser package)

Tags: express, cookies, session-cookies

i am using cookie parser in express to store the token in cookie and access it later, the token is stored in the cookie but i am unable to access it using req.cookies
here is sambles of my codes

package.json

```
{  
  "type": "module",
   ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    ...
  }
```

index.js

```
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
...

app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));
app.use(cookieParser());
...
```

when login

```
    ...
    res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 100,
    });
    ...
```

for accessing the cookie

```
 const response = await axios.get(
        "http://localhost:5000/token",
        { withCredentials: true }
      );
// -----------------------
// and at the /token I have this function

    const refreshToken = req.cookies.refreshToken;
    if (!refreshToken) {
      return res.status(401).json({msg: refreshToken});
    }
    ...
```

when trying to access the cookie using

```
    const refreshToken = req.cookies.refreshToken;
    if (!refreshToken) {
      return res.sendStatus(401);
    }
    ...
```

the if condition always true i tried to console.log(req.cookies.refreshToken) but it says undefined
this was the last task i needed to finish my project
please help thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and worked for me for some reason:

```js
try {
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

  const response = await axios.get(
    "http://localhost:5000/collections/token"
  );
  ...
} catch (error) {
  ...
}
```

And the core and the login is still the same:

```
// the core at index.js
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));
    
// login js 
res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {
  httpOnly: true,
  maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 100,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

// post request
const response = await axios.post(
  'url',
  { name : 'xxx' },
  { withCredentials: true }
);

// get request
const response = await axios.get(
  'url',
  { withCredentials: true }
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: no, it still read empty it doesn't work i will update the post

Comment: Thankyou for help sheikh Farid